# Best way to access data from mysql db on other non-local machines

Tags: python, mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have read a few posts on how to enable remote login to mysql. My question is: is this a safe way to access data remotely?

I have a my sql db located at home (on Ubuntu 14.04) that I use for research purposes. I would like to run python scripts from my Macbook at work. I was able to remote login from my old windows OS using workbench connection (DNS ip). However the OS change has got me thinking what is the best/most secure way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ssh to login to your home computer, setup authorized keys for it and disable password login. setup iptables on your linux machine if you don't have a firewall on your router, and disable traffic on all ports except 80 and 22 (ssh and internet). That should get you started.